# Check if a DLL is signed C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, windows-7, digital-signature

I am trying to check if a DLL is signed based on the file path. I see that there are pre-existing solutions for this type of problem using WinVerifyTrust, however, when I tried checking it against "C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll" it said: "The file "C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll" is not signed." although kernel32 should be a signed dll. I am on Windows 7 fyi.

This is the source code to the function I called: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382384(v=vs.85).aspx

How can I fix the function?

Comment: When I ran that app on Windows 10: `The file "c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll" is signed and the signature was verified.`

Comment: fwiw, if you compiled that code as 32-bit (the default for Visual Studio), but ran on 64-bit OS, the file access gets for c:\windows\system32 gets redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.  Can you manually check that the kernel32.dll in syswow64 is code signed?  Also, since kernel32.dll is probably a very special DLL subject to other possible redirection stuff, manually copy it to another directory and rename it.  Then run the code on the copied file again to see if it has any differences.

Comment: I have to compile it as 32-bit, when I tried kernel32.dll in syswow same message "The file "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll" is not signed". I tried putting the dll in C:\ and same message. I'm looking for a global solution so maybe it doesn't work on windows 7 but need something for all operating systems past vista.

Comment: Are you actually trying to validate kernel32.dll specifically, or any other DLL?  (Does that winverifytrust api work on other code-signed binaries from other products that those that are built into Windows?)

Comment: Any dll that is signed. I tried a overlay dll and it said "The file "C:\overlay.x64.dll" is signed and the signature was verified.". However, I need the function to return true even if it is a windows dll.

Comment: Well, if it's a Windows DLL, it's signed. You don't need a function to tell you that.

Comment: Yes, so how do I check if its a windows DLL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `WinVerifyTrust` is the correct function to use but you have to be prepared to call it twice.

First you call it with [`WTD_CHOICE_FILE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382384(v=vs.85).aspx), if that succeeds then you are done. If not, you must call it again with `WTD_CHOICE_CATALOG` (`CryptCATAdminCalcHashFromFileHandle` + `CryptCATAdminEnumCatalogFromHash` + `CryptCATCatalogInfoFromContext`) because some Windows files do not embed the certificate information (especially non-PE files). (You can also try to [find the catalog info first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2013/08/07/using-winverifytrust-api-to-verify-detached-signatures-for-executable-files.aspx) to avoid calling it twice but I assume this is slower)

There are various threads ([this](https://forum.sysinternals.com/sigcheck-functionality_topic16893.html) and [this](https://forum.sysinternals.com/howto-verify-the-digital-signature-of-a-file_topic19247.html)) on the Sysinternals forum is perhaps the best resource for questions related to this.